# Settings doesn't update on live wallpaper preview at runtime in Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

While doing a live wallpaper i follow [This Tutorial](http://www.androidtutorials.org/live-wallpaper-in-android/) and do exactly what they said.
All works good there, but the problem is when an option is changed from **settings** page, then it doesn't change immediately in preview mode. I need to restart the wallpaper from wallpaper chooser to see that change.
So can anyone point what i need to add there to see the immediate changes? Some solutions of **SO** suggests,`getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences(). unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` can do the trick in `onDestroy()`, but above solution don't applied `SharedPreferences`. So what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i customize that project, give up `Preference` and convert it to `SharedPreferences`, now it works good as i want earlier.
You need to use this line in `onDestroy()`:    `getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`
And this line in `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`:
    `getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`
That's all..